# Error occuring template parsing. (Spring Boot + Thymeleaf) || Whitelabel Error

Tags: html, spring-boot, thymeleaf

My index.html file and the error is as follows.

[Index.html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwxBA.png)

[Thymeleaf error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u47ax.png)

[Whitelabel error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8KXa6.png)

Can anyone tell what is causing the error, I've tried adding $ instead of @, still getting error message. I'm new to spring boot.

Comment: I believe you have `th: src` (with space after colon) instead of `th:src`.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.